# How to remove square corners when border-radius is set in Qt?

Tags: css, qt

I switched my whole stylesheet to `border-radius: 10px` to give my program a more modern appareance:
[image: Rounded corners]

However, sometimes the rounded corners are against a black background and the result isn't pretty:
[image: When it goes wrong]

Is there a way to remove the extraneous square corners?
Here's the stylesheet: https://github.com/Kobo-InkBox/inkbox/blob/5ad4e773661a56801712ea9d59adf6d54c1bbca4/resources/eink.qss

Comment: Note that it's going to be very difficult to diagnose the problem without seeing the code (read 'widget hierarchy') to which the stylesheet is being applied.

Comment: https://github.com/Kobo-InkBox/inkbox

Comment: You posted a link to a really large project. No one wants to read through thousands of lines of code to figure out where your problem is. That's why we ask for a [mre].

Comment: Please attach the code where problem occur

Comment: @Farshid616 Well, the problem occurs everywhere where there are rounded corners (buttons, dialogs, etc.) because the main stylesheet I linked in my question has the border-radius set to 10px for almost every element that can (e.g. https://github.com/Kobo-InkBox/inkbox/blob/4b305738993beb1da3eaebee67329735c4c4162c/resources/eink.qss#L44). I can't really post a specific part of the program where this happens.

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing much about Ubuntu, I can only answer with Windows.

If this dialog is a top level window which doesn't have a parent, actually the lowest background color may depend on operating system characteristics, I have no idea because maybe it must be a square window.

If you really need to make it a rounded rectangle, you need to set this property in constructor to make it able to be transparent.

```
setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
```

Then draw a rounded rectangle as background in paintEvent.

Answer (score 0):

You should also set the `radius: 10` for you rectangles if they are **not** transparent. This should solve your problem.

Or let borders to shape as their base rectangle, I mean you can remove your border-radius and instead add radius to your rectangles where you need round corners.